# Create colorbox gallery popup from different div click?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

This is the JS code that I've been tweaking to try and get the colorbox gallery to popup on click of the $('#sv') element:

```
$('#sv').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.svItem').colorbox({
        width: '80%',
        rel: 'gallery',
        href: function () {
            return $(this).data('href');
        },
        title: function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }
    });
});
```

and here's what the generated HTML looks like that I need to query:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="sv">
    <div class="homeButton" style="background-image: url('/images/menu/btn_sv.png');">
        <div id="svItem0" class="svItem" rel="gallery" data-href="/images/sv/1.jpg" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="svItem1" class="svItem" rel="gallery" data-href="/images/sv/2.jpg" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="svItem2" class="svItem" rel="gallery" data-href="/images/sv/3.jpg" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="svItem3" class="svItem" rel="gallery" data-href="/images/sv/4.jpg" style="display:none"></div>
        <h2 class="homeTitle shadow">
            Le saviez-vous?
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by adding "**open: true**" with:

```
$('#sv').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.svItem').colorbox({
        width: '80%',
        open: true,
        rel: 'gallery',
        href: function () {
            return $(this).data('href');
        }
    });
});
```